# Change Background Color With a Fading Effect

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to change my background color of my GameScene from black to white with a fading effect. How would I do this? I've tried using animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:

```
self.run(SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.white, colorBlendFactor: 1, 
duration: 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.viewForBackGroundChange.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    })
```

This should work. I have taken the example of a view here, replace that with the background layer of which ever component you wish to use.

Comment: This seems to instantly change it to red. UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, animations: {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }

Comment: yeah, play around with the duration, which ever works for you.

Comment: Even if I set the duration to 10,000 it still changes instantly.

Comment: which components background are you trying to change? In the example its a UIView, works perfect on my end.

Comment: My GameScene's background

Comment: I figured it out: self.run(SKAction.colorize(with: UIColor.white, colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 10))